# How to design two types of account in a system

Tags: c#, .net, oop, user-management

I am trying to create a social networking application for students and teachers.
I am currently designing the user accounts module

I have thought of these two approaches

Approach 1

```
Public class Account
{
    public string AccountId{get;set;}
    public string AccountName{get;set;}
       .
       .
       .


}

public class Student : Account
{
    public Course[] Courses {get; set;}
    //other student properties
        .
        .
        .

}

public class Teacher : Account
{
     //other teacher properties

}
```

Approach 2

```
Public class Account
{
    public string AccountId{get;set;}
    public string AccountName{get;set;}
    public AccountType AccountType {get;set;}  //AccontType is enum having student and teacher
       .
       .
       .


}


public class User
{
    public string UserId { get;set;}
    public string UserName {get;set;}
    public Account Account {get;set;}
}


public class Student : User
{
    public Course[] Courses {get; set;}
    //other student properties
        .
        .
        .

}


public class Teacher : User
{
     //other teacher properties

}
```

Is there any better approach than these approaches?

Answer (score 2):

Approach 2 is much clearer and preferred in my opinion.

What it comes down to is does a `User` *have an account* or *is* a `User` an account? For me its the former and you should use composition instead of inheritance in this case as you do in approach 2.

Comment: have you encountered any such scenarios...and are there any standard practices regarding this...

Answer (score 1):

I like approach 2 better because it's more closer to the real world scenario.  Students and Teachers **are** users and each of them **have an** account with the desired properties set.